# How should one use external Images in VS2010?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, image, resources

How should one use Images that **must not be embedded** in the Assembly (e.g. because of licensing issues)?

The Images should be **accessible from all Projects** in the current Solution and have to **be usable in Design-Time**.

I tried using linked resources but had no luck.
The Designer wasn't able to load the non-embedded resx-File.
I didn't even try to use the Resource-File in multiple Projects.

Comment: so you want to embed images without embedding them, and use copyrighted material without paying..

Comment: you may use placeholder images that you substitute programmatically at runtime.

Comment: @vulkanino Said material is LGPL-licensed and not for sale

Comment: @vulkanino I currently got whitespace instead of images. Makes the Images hard to distinguish. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a UserControl, set the size of the control then add a PictureBox and dock it to fill the control, on the code load the image you want from the place you want and then you just have to add the control where you would put the image.

It's not a tiddy way but it works.

In the user control the code should look like this:

```
namespace TestImage
{
    public partial class ImageControl : UserControl
    {
        public ImageControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            /// image.png should be placed in the IDE folder or use the fullpath/url instead and also in the output directory.

            this.pictureBox1.ImageLocation = @".\image.png";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need the images accessible at Design-Time. When I just do `Image.FromFile(@".\image.png")` the designer won't find it. I also don't see the advantage of a UserControl.

Comment: As vulkanino said, you can't embed an image without embedding it. Then the only solution it cames to me is to use a picturebox, but if you do that you'll need to write code everytime you need the image. So creating and additional control accessible within the Toolbox and then in the Load event or also in the contructor you load the image this.PictureBox1.ImageLocation = "YourLocation" you have an image accessible at design-time. Remember to build each time you change the control.